# Methods to solve integer linear inequalities with products of two variables

Tags: linear-programming, reference-request, nonlinear-programming, nonconvex-programming

I'm interested in solving the following system of equations over the integers:

\begin{align*}
x_l^3 &\le x_l^1x_l^2 & \text{ for } l = 1,\ldots,s \\
A x &\le b \\
0 &\le x
\end{align*}
where $x_l^j$ are components in $x$. There are [methods](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2946479?seq=1) to solve the case where $x_l^1 = x_l^2$. But I know of no analogous results for the "hyperbolic" case. My main interesting is in checking that there is a small solution.

Answer (score 2):

One classic technique is to reformulate the integer variables as a bunch of binary variables. In this case i would use a encoding with powers of 2 and then use a multiplier circuit to express the multiplication. Since multiplicaiton circuits are made out of ANDs and ORs the resulting problem will be MILP.

Bi-linear terms (and also monomial terms which all can be expressed as nested bi-linear terms) can be over approximated using McCormick envelopes. Some MINLP solvers (i am aware that Alpine.jl does that) use this to express products.

I would recommend throwing some MINLP solvers at is first and see how they do. If that proves infeasible see if you have success with a binary linear formulation and see if MILP solvers help you. If all your variables are binary and MILP solvers fail to find feasible solutions try [Exact](https://gitlab.com/JoD/exact).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was looking for methods that solve this specific case similar to the method proposed in the linked paper.